# Ubuntu 16 - How to make Systemd keep on trying to start service even when start condition failed?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, systemd

I have a sytemd unit file for kafka like below.

```
[Unit]
Description=Apache Kafka server (broker)
Documentation=http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html
After=network.target remote-fs.target kafka-zookeeper.service

[Service]
Type=simple
User=nano
Group=nano
Environment=JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_102
ExecStart=/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-server-start.sh /opt/kafka/config/server.properties
ExecStop=/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-server-stop.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
RestartSec=2s
Restart=always
```

Zookeeper unit file.

```
[Service]
Type=simple
User=nano
Group=nano
Environment=JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_102
ExecStart=/opt/kafka/bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh /opt/kafka/config/zookeeper.properties
ExecStop=/opt/kafka/bin/zookeeper-server-stop.sh
RestartSec=2s
Restart=always
```

Sometimes I am observing that kafka is in a stopped state and doing `systemctl status kafka.service` showing me the below message

```
ubuntu@platform3:/usr/lib/systemd/system$ sudo systemctl status kafka.service
● kafka.service - Kafka Service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/kafka.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
Condition: start condition failed at Mon 2019-03-25 17:56:30 UTC; 10h ago
```

On checking logs it seems when `sudo systemctl start kafka.service` was executed that time zookeeper was not running . So the pre-condition did not meet and kafka did not start.

But after sometime zookeeper was up and running but even then Kafka did not start. Can someone let me know if there is a way I can make systemd keep on trying to start kafka and not just stop once if pre-conditions are not met like the way it is happening now?

Answer (score 0):

Use `kafka-zookeeper.service` in `Require=` instead of `After=`. This will do, that your service will first look if zookeeper is running, and if its not running, it will try to start it.

Based on documentation: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/systemd.unit.5.html

Comment: Rather than starting zookeeper can kafka wait for it to get started?

Comment: Then you could do `After=` as you did, but go for `Restart=always` under `[Service]`, this will do that, systemd will automatically restarts kafka.service until it start successfully. There are some other options in doc related to that Restart, you should read about them.

Comment: I added `Restart=Always` it does not help. If pre-conditions fails then `Restart=` does not take effect. https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2014-November/025122.html